# req.context["start_time"] in Falcon

Tags: python, docker, api, rest, falconframework

What does **req.context["start_time"]** give when the **FalconAPI** is deployed on

i) a server which has it's time set to UTC?
Actually, here my API is running in a **docker container** whose time is set to **UTC**.
The actual server time is **UTC + 05:30**

ii) a server which has it's time set to any other timezone? Eg. **UTC + 05:30** (India)